# Reference Request; Existence of Limit

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebraic-groups, pseudoinverse

**Background/thoughts**

---

Since $GL_d(\mathbb{R})$ is a topological group then the maps $A\mapsto A^{-1}$ and $(B,A)\mapsto A+B$ are continuous.  Therefore, in the case where $X \in GL_d(\mathbb{R})$ then $GL_d(\mathbb{R})$, it follows that
$$
\lim_{k \downarrow 0} (X+k I_d)^{-1} =X^{-1}
.
$$

**Question:**

---

In general however, for $k>0$ and $X$ any $d\times d$ matrix $X+kI_d\in GL_d(\mathbb{R})$ but what is the limit equal to *(since $GL_d(\mathbb{R})$ is open as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{d^2}$ therefore it need not contain all its limits...)*
$$
\lim_{k \downarrow 0} (X+k I_d)^{-1} =?
.
$$
Does it equal to the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse?

Comment: Have you thought about the case where $X$ is the zero matrix, or $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}$?

Comment: So it really only makes sense when $X$ has non-trivial diagonal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit may not exists in all cases.

Without loss of generality we first check whether this limit exists for our scalar field $\Bbb C$. Suppose $X$ has $0$ as its eigen value. Then it has a Jordan-Block $B_{n\times n}$ corresponding to $0$. But note that, $\lim_{k \to 0} (B+k I_n)^{-1}$ does not exists : $\text{det}(B+k I_n)=k^n$, so finding inverse using classical adjoint techniques we have the result, actually $(1,1)$ entry will be $\frac{1}{k}$.

So the above limit exists if $X$ has no zero eigen value, hence invertible.

Answer (score 0):

In general the limit does not exist. For example let $X=0$. Then

$$(X+kI_d)^{-1}=\frac{1}{k}I_d.$$

Comment: Are there conditions on $X$ for the limit to exist (other than $X \in GL_d(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Suppose that $\lim_{k \downarrow 0} (X+k I_d)^{-1}$ exists. Call it $A$. Then we have $I_d=(X+k I_d)^{-1})(X+kI_d) \to AX$ as $k \to 0.$ Thus $I_d=AX$, hence $X$ is invertible.

Comment: If instead ask if the limit $\lim_{k \downarrow 0} \lim_{k \downarrow 0} (X+k I_d)^{+}$ exists, where $Y^+$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse then would this still be meaningless?